# Writing Objects in PipedWriter Java

Tags: java, stream

I'm implementing pipe and filter architecture in java, i'm stuck in scenario in which my in my `FilterWriter` class i want to send an object over java io's [PipedWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PipedWriter.html), and on the other hand `FilterReader` class ([PipedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PipedReader.html)) will read this object and extract info out of it. But it looks like these class can only write the following types:

[image]

Is there any i can send and receive objects over these reader classes?
What is the other appropriate way of sending objects through streams in Pipe Filter architecture?

I want to do something like [this](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/pipes.html), but i want to write and read objects instead of strings or bytes.. how can i do it?

Comment: If you want to transfer objects between threads in the same JVM, use something like `java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue`.

Answer (score 0):

To write Java objects (Serializables) you need PipedOutputStream instead of PipedWriter

```
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new PipedOutputStream(sink));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but, i want to do this http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/pipes.html but writing and reading objects instead of strings or bytes.. how can i do it with ObjectOutputStream() ?

Comment: ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(obj) - but obj must be Serializable